what permissions should i give to a plex server
so im setting up a plex server on an old laptop that i have.
the laptop is running 'ubuntu server' os.
i installed qbittorrent-nox and all the downloads going to the folder

/home/qbittorrent-nox/movies

now when i go into the plex web interface and trying to add a library i can't find the folders (due to permissions).
i tried to

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/qbittorrent-nox

and it works.
my question is, is that ok to have all the permissions 'open' like this? if not what should i set it to?

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/qbittorrent-nox that is always bad. General idea: 750 directories and files 640 unless you need to execute then -those- files 750. If you have 1 user on the machine the 2nd digit (group) can be 0 too if you want. The 3rd digit (others) set that only if you have visitors on your system.

when i go with 750 plex can see the folders and access them, but when i try to play a file  i get an error that plex can't access the file

see my comment at the answer by terrance... use a common group for your user and plex

Movies / media files don't need to be eXecutable, nor does Plex make any changes to the files, so the permissions of 664 or -rw-rw-r-- should be enough for the Plex Media Server to read the files.  Also with 664 it will prevent users that are not part of the group or the actual owner / user of the file from deleting it.  Remember that having sudo access will override any file / directory permissions.
EDIT: Well, PMS can delete the files so maybe permissions of 666 might be good if Plex is not in the group or the owner of the files.

only 1 comment on this " if Plex is not in the group or the owner of the files." .... then you add user or plex to the group ;)

can you explain how to do it? totally noob here

@user23887851 It is just like the command you ran in your question but change 777 to 664.  No need for sudo since the files should not be owned by root.
